# Traversing XML in Python

Tags: python, xml

I've got some very 'deep' XML (see e.g. at the bottom) and am struggling to get to the values I need using either minidom or elementtree - any idea what the simplest way of getting to the bolded values (VALUE_TO_GET) are given that there will be a different number of `LowestOfferListing` tags? I basically need to get the first instance of `LandedPrice`/`Amount` for each `SKUIdentifier` and can't find a simple(ish) way of doing so!

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<GetLowestOfferListingsForSKUResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01">
  <GetLowestOfferListingsForSKUResult SellerSKU="X" status="Success">
    <AllOfferListingsConsidered>true</AllOfferListingsConsidered>
    <Product xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01" 
             xmlns:ns2="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd">
      <Identifiers>
        <MarketplaceASIN>
          <MarketplaceId>X</MarketplaceId>
          <ASIN>X</ASIN>
        </MarketplaceASIN>
        <SKUIdentifier>
          <MarketplaceId>X</MarketplaceId>
          <SellerId>X</SellerId>
          <SellerSKU>**VALUE_TO_GET**</SellerSKU>
        </SKUIdentifier>
      </Identifiers>
      <LowestOfferListings>
        <LowestOfferListing>
          <Qualifiers>
            <ItemCondition>New</ItemCondition>
            <ItemSubcondition>New</ItemSubcondition>
            <FulfillmentChannel>Amazon</FulfillmentChannel>
            <ShipsDomestically>True</ShipsDomestically>
            <ShippingTime>
              <Max>X</Max>
            </ShippingTime>
            <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>X</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
          </Qualifiers>
          <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>3</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
          <SellerFeedbackCount>X</SellerFeedbackCount>
          <Price>
            <LandedPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>**VALUE_TO_GET**</Amount>
            </LandedPrice>
            <ListingPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </ListingPrice>
            <Shipping>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </Shipping>
          </Price>
          <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>False</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
        </LowestOfferListing>
        <LowestOfferListing>
          <Qualifiers>
            <ItemCondition>X</ItemCondition>
            <ItemSubcondition>X</ItemSubcondition>
            <FulfillmentChannel>Merchant</FulfillmentChannel>
            <ShipsDomestically>X</ShipsDomestically>
            <ShippingTime>
              <Max>X</Max>
            </ShippingTime>
            <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>X</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
          </Qualifiers>
          <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>X</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
          <SellerFeedbackCount>X</SellerFeedbackCount>
          <Price>
            <LandedPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </LandedPrice>
            <ListingPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </ListingPrice>
            <Shipping>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </Shipping>
          </Price>
          <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>X</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
        </LowestOfferListing>
        <LowestOfferListing>
          <Qualifiers>
            <ItemCondition>X</ItemCondition>
            <ItemSubcondition>X</ItemSubcondition>
            <FulfillmentChannel>X</FulfillmentChannel>
            <ShipsDomestically>X</ShipsDomestically>
            <ShippingTime>
              <Max>X</Max>
            </ShippingTime>
            <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>X</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
          </Qualifiers>
          <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>X</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
          <SellerFeedbackCount>X</SellerFeedbackCount>
          <Price>
            <LandedPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </LandedPrice>
            <ListingPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </ListingPrice>
            <Shipping>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </Shipping>
          </Price>
          <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>X</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
        </LowestOfferListing>
        <LowestOfferListing>
          <Qualifiers>
            <ItemCondition>X</ItemCondition>
            <ItemSubcondition>X</ItemSubcondition>
            <FulfillmentChannel>X</FulfillmentChannel>
            <ShipsDomestically>X</ShipsDomestically>
            <ShippingTime>
              <Max>X</Max>
            </ShippingTime>
            <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>X</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
          </Qualifiers>
          <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>X</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
          <SellerFeedbackCount>X</SellerFeedbackCount>
          <Price>
            <LandedPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </LandedPrice>
            <ListingPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </ListingPrice>
            <Shipping>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </Shipping>
          </Price>
          <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>X</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
        </LowestOfferListing>
        <LowestOfferListing>
          <Qualifiers>
            <ItemCondition>X</ItemCondition>
            <ItemSubcondition>X</ItemSubcondition>
            <FulfillmentChannel>X</FulfillmentChannel>
            <ShipsDomestically>X</ShipsDomestically>
            <ShippingTime>
              <Max>X</Max>
            </ShippingTime>
            <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>X</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
          </Qualifiers>
          <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>X</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
          <SellerFeedbackCount>X</SellerFeedbackCount>
          <Price>
            <LandedPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </LandedPrice>
            <ListingPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </ListingPrice>
            <Shipping>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </Shipping>
          </Price>
          <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>X</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
        </LowestOfferListing>
      </LowestOfferListings>
    </Product>
  </GetLowestOfferListingsForSKUResult>
  <GetLowestOfferListingsForSKUResult SellerSKU="X" status="X">
    <AllOfferListingsConsidered>X</AllOfferListingsConsidered>
    <Product xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01"
             xmlns:ns2="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd">
      <Identifiers>
        <MarketplaceASIN>
          <MarketplaceId>X</MarketplaceId>
          <ASIN>X</ASIN>
        </MarketplaceASIN>
        <SKUIdentifier>
          <MarketplaceId>X</MarketplaceId>
          <SellerId>X</SellerId>
          <SellerSKU>**VALUE_TO_GET**</SellerSKU>
        </SKUIdentifier>
      </Identifiers>
      <LowestOfferListings>
        <LowestOfferListing>
          <Qualifiers>
            <ItemCondition>X</ItemCondition>
            <ItemSubcondition>X</ItemSubcondition>
            <FulfillmentChannel>X</FulfillmentChannel>
            <ShipsDomestically>X</ShipsDomestically>
            <ShippingTime>
              <Max>X</Max>
            </ShippingTime>
            <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>X</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
          </Qualifiers>
          <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>1</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
          <SellerFeedbackCount>X</SellerFeedbackCount>
          <Price>
            <LandedPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>**VALUE_TO_GET**</Amount>
            </LandedPrice>
            <ListingPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </ListingPrice>
            <Shipping>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </Shipping>
          </Price>
          <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>X</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
        </LowestOfferListing>
        <LowestOfferListing>
          <Qualifiers>
            <ItemCondition>X</ItemCondition>
            <ItemSubcondition>X</ItemSubcondition>
            <FulfillmentChannel>X</FulfillmentChannel>
            <ShipsDomestically>X</ShipsDomestically>
            <ShippingTime>
              <Max>X</Max>
            </ShippingTime>
            <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>X</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
          </Qualifiers>
          <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>8</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
          <SellerFeedbackCount>X</SellerFeedbackCount>
          <Price>
            <LandedPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </LandedPrice>
            <ListingPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </ListingPrice>
            <Shipping>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </Shipping>
          </Price>
          <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>X</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
        </LowestOfferListing>
        <LowestOfferListing>
          <Qualifiers>
            <ItemCondition>X</ItemCondition>
            <ItemSubcondition>X</ItemSubcondition>
            <FulfillmentChannel>Merchant</FulfillmentChannel>
            <ShipsDomestically>X</ShipsDomestically>
            <ShippingTime>
              <Max>X</Max>
            </ShippingTime>
            <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>X</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
          </Qualifiers>
          <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>4</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
          <SellerFeedbackCount>X</SellerFeedbackCount>
          <Price>
            <LandedPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </LandedPrice>
            <ListingPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </ListingPrice>
            <Shipping>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </Shipping>
          </Price>
          <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>X</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
        </LowestOfferListing>
        <LowestOfferListing>
          <Qualifiers>
            <ItemCondition>X</ItemCondition>
            <ItemSubcondition>X</ItemSubcondition>
            <FulfillmentChannel>X</FulfillmentChannel>
            <ShipsDomestically>X</ShipsDomestically>
            <ShippingTime>
              <Max>X</Max>
            </ShippingTime>
            <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>X</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
          </Qualifiers>
          <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>1</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
          <SellerFeedbackCount>X</SellerFeedbackCount>
          <Price>
            <LandedPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </LandedPrice>
            <ListingPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </ListingPrice>
            <Shipping>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </Shipping>
          </Price>
          <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>X</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
        </LowestOfferListing>
      </LowestOfferListings>
    </Product>
  </GetLowestOfferListingsForSKUResult>
  <ResponseMetadata>
    <RequestId>X</RequestId>
  </ResponseMetadata>
</GetLowestOfferListingsForSKUResponse>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you xml seems not to be valid, as it gives an error with `elemntree`, so I tried it with `lxml.html`, that is more robust, the `xpath` though, remains the same.

```
import lxml.html as lh
doc=lh.fromstring(xml)
doc.xpath('//sellersku/text()|//product/descendant::amount[1]/text()')
```

*output:*

```
['**VALUE_TO_GET**',
 '**VALUE_TO_GET**',
 '**VALUE_TO_GET**',
 '**VALUE_TO_GET**']
```

Comment: The XML is well-formed. It was just badly formatted before my edit.

Comment: @root Thanks for the answer - have never used lxml before but it seems like it may be the way forward. However, the example you've given is only returning the first two **VALUE_TO_GET** for me. I get (I think) that we're isolating the `//sellersku/text()` and piping the results of that to find `//product/descendant` and `amount[1]/text()` - is there a way to do this recursively and find all instances of this (as the actual list will include thousands of products)?

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: @root Sorry but I don't understand your comment. Are you saying that there are two of those values in the xml? Or that the expression `doc.xpath('//sellersku/text()|//product/descendant::amount[1]/text()')` contains two of `//sellersku/text()` and `//product`?

This approach is doing what I want it to except that it is only taking the first instance of the sellersku and amount it finds in the xml whereas I would like it to find all first child instances per sellersku.

I want to use it to pull those bits of info into a dictionary with sellersku as the key and amount as the value.

Comment: @Kali_89 -- the pipe char `|` lets you combine two separate expressions together. `//sellersku/text()` finds all the sellerSKU tags and `//product/descendant::amount[1]/text()` finds the first amount tag of every product.

Comment: @root That's OK - have got it. Solution you posted was right and my data set had changed hence I was getting unexpected results. Thanks for all the help!